# Using android-maps-utils with ADT

Tags: android, google-maps, adt

I am trying to use this library [1] in an Android project with a fresh installation of ADT. I just don't know what to do. The library seems to use some VCS and something called gradle (a build tool so it seems).

Could someone please tell me what steps are neccessary to integrate that library into an own android project using a fresh install of ADT!

Thank you very much!

[1] https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, download it to your computer. If you don't use git, just press Download ZIP in the bottom right corner.

Then you have some options (from the easist):

1. Copy res and src folders from the [library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/master/library) folder directly to your project. This should be ok as long as you keep the license info.
2. Copy some `project.properties` into `library` folder. Now the library project will be importable in Eclipse.
3. Use Android Studio, which has support for Gradle.

Comment: The first approach actually worked. Had to rename some namespaces or imports to fit my project architecture but then it just worked. Thanks a lot! I didn't try the second one because I didn't understand it. I tried the third suggestion two weeks ago. Unfortunately gradle integration in Android Studio is not complete and as a beginner, I wasn't able to configure it manually - It demolished the whole project and had to reinstall everything.