# how to draw text in default marker of google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to draw text in default marker of Google map v2. I have done this by taking my own image from drawable but how can i change it in default marker.

my code is

```
 marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
          .fromBitmap(drawTextToBitmap(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.images,"5")));
```

and `drawTextToBitmap`methods is.

```
public static Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context gContext,int gResId,String gText) {
    Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Bitmap bitmap =
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);

    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =
            bitmap.getConfig();
    if(bitmapConfig == null) {
        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize((int) (15 * scale));
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
    int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width())/2;
    int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height())/2;

    canvas.drawText(gText, x * scale, y * scale, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

i want to draw text like that

[image]

Comment: have you looked at info windows?https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i have looked. info window only show text above the marker but i want to show text inside the marker.

Comment: check this https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils or this Or the new website: http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/ and this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nb2X9IjjZpM

Comment: check the answer posted and don't forget to accept the same if it helps.

Comment: the markers are very small. 1-2 letters should fit in it

Comment: @NumanAhmad did you try the below. you can add text to the markers is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Raghunandan i don't want to make bubble i want to show text inside the original marker.

Comment: @Numan Ahmad, did you ever figure out how to write over the default marker that comes with google maps?

Comment: Its not working with my own image.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.Downlaod the library from

github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

2.To use check this link

[Using android-maps-utils with ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796464/using-android-maps-utils-with-adt/17796692#17796692)

```
  TextIconGenerator tc = new TextIconGenerator(this);
  Bitmap bmp = tc.makeIcon("hello");
```

Then   set the bitmap to the map object

```
  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
```

snap shot

[image]

Comment: how can i show text inside the marker?I dont want to make a bubble like you made.

Comment: i want to draw text like that


![i want to draw text like that][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ2aJ.jpg

Comment: you need a bubble bitmap and then draw the text as you did.

Comment: how can i do that using bubble bitmap please give me example?

Comment: there is default resource icon. you need to make a bubble icon and that have the same in drawable folder

Comment: Hello, i have implemented text over maker but i want to set text pudding on marker image, it is not changing its position.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this example to draw text in marker you have to set latlong:

```
public Marker showTextOnMarker(final Context context, final GoogleMap map,
        final LatLng location, final String text, final int padding,
        final int fontSize) {
    Marker marker = null;

    if (context == null || map == null || location == null || text == null
            || fontSize <= 0) {
        return marker;
    }

    final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextSize(fontSize);

    final Paint paintText = textView.getPaint();

    final Rect boundsText = new Rect();
    paintText.getTextBounds(text, 0, textView.length(), boundsText);
    paintText.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

    final Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    final Bitmap bmpText = Bitmap.createBitmap(boundsText.width() + 2
            * padding, boundsText.height() + 2 * padding, conf);

    final Canvas canvasText = new Canvas(bmpText);
    paintText.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    canvasText.drawText(text, canvasText.getWidth() / 2,
            canvasText.getHeight() - padding - boundsText.bottom, paintText);

    final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(location)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmpText))
            .anchor(0.5f, 1);

    marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

    return marker;
}
```