# customize the pin of map Android

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, marker

Hello I would like to add a dynamic display with a number in my point.

As in the picture, I already have the icons on the map.

Adding the numbers in point?

[image]

Comment: looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335642/how-to-draw-text-in-default-marker-of-google-map-v2/18336950#18336950?

Comment: No, i have the icon (pin), but the numbers I get dynamically and set each pin.. Do you understand?

Comment: use infowindows. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: I saw this, but i want that the numbers show without clicking on pin...

Comment: don't think its possible unless you find some third party library that helps you achieve the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [android-maps-utils](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) to achieve such effect.

Simply create 9-patch out of your pin with empty rectangle above and make rectangle be the content.

Then use `IconGenerator` to create a `Bitmap` with your text and 9-patch like here:

```
IconGenerator factory = new IconGenerator(context);
factory.setBackground(your9PatchDrawable);
factory.setContentView(textViewWithWith3Point600String);
Bitmap icon = factory.makeIcon();
```

Then use this `Bitmap` to set `Marker`s icon:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)...);
```

Comment: Yes! exactly this.. but i can't import the library in Eclipse... The lib don't shows me when i try to import it... Do you know how can i do this?

Comment: It's works, THANKS!! But the BubbleIconFactory is deprecated i used TextIconGenerator, is the same... thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisBroadfoot These classes change names too often ;)

Comment: @MaciejGórski I know! Sorry. It only changed once between 0.1 and 0.2 though! (but another time on HEAD)

Comment: @MaciejGórski  :factory.setContentView(textViewWithWith3Point600String); What is the argument here. Can a simple text view be put in that?

Comment: @Ashwin Yes. I thought that variable `textViewWithWith3Point600String` would be good enough to describe that it's a simple `TextView` with `"3.600"` as its text.

Comment: @MaciejGórski : But then why is this not working - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384422/android-map-utils-text-not-showing-in-custom-marker-content

Comment: @Ashwin I don't know. The API of that library had a few breaking changes, so it's possible you do that differently right now. Might be worth asking on [android-maps-utils issues](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues).

Comment: I need the same for iOS... does anyone know how to do it for iOS ?

Comment: I've done this but the icon is stretching as well, distorting the whole image! How can I define the TextView to be the only part to be stretched? Can you guys provide more detail on this solution? I'd be immensely grateful, getting mad on this.

Comment: @faboolous, i did this using the setContentView method, you just need to have a textview with id "text" in that view. http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html#setContentView-View-