# Android : add numbers to map markers

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on a map that has multiple markers on it. These markers use a custom icon.

Is there a way to add numbers to these icons ?

edit: here is an example of what I want to do

[image]

I want to generate these icons programmatically and add them to the map.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>first, you can use [library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18336950/3215911).</s>

or, you should implement custom icons into drawable folder and put code below.

`MarkerOptions markeropt = new MarkerOptions();
markeropt.snippet("Snippet");
markeropt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.custom_icon));`

[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763545/android-maps-api-v2-with-custom-markers) would be helpful!
here is a link's snippet.

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; 
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 50, conf); 
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

canvas.drawText("TEXT", 0, 50, paint); // paint defines the text color, stroke width, size
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(clickedPosition)
                                //.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker2))
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp))
                                .anchor(0.5f, 1)
                                    );
```

Comment: I'm not sure the library does what I need, i have added some details to my question.

Comment: The second option will of course work but to do it i have to manually generate the icons i will use with all the possible numbers

Comment: then, [another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763545/android-maps-api-v2-with-custom-markers) would be helpful.

Comment: Yes this one is helpful, please add it to your answer